# Filter in django: the last post of each user

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have 2 models, Author and Post , how can I make a filter who can select the last post (by id field) of each Author in one only line?, the bad approach for me is :

```
authors = Author.objects.all()
queryset = []
for author in authors:
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author=author).order_by('-id')
    if loc:
        queryset.append(posts[0])
```

Specifically, this is to filter my Tastypie Resource "PostResource", a filter who can give me only the last post of each user, ordered by creation

### Complete solution with okm answer and tastypie custom filter:

```
class LocationResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(AccountResource,'user' )
    class Meta:
        queryset = Location.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        resource_name = 'location'
        #excludes = ['id',]
        list_allowed_methods = ['post','get']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization= Authorization()
        filtering = {'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS}

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        if bundle.request.method == 'POST':
            return super(LocationResource, self).obj_create(bundle, user=bundle.request.user)

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(user=request.user)

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        return bundle

    def build_filters(self, filters=None):
        if filters is None: #if you don't pass any filters at all
            filters = {}

        orm_filters = super(LocationResource, self).build_filters(filters)

        if('only_lasts' in filters):

            query = filters['only_lasts']

            sqs = Location.objects.values('user_id').annotate(max_id=models.Max('id')).values('max_id')

            orm_filters["pk__in"] = sqs

        return orm_filters
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [the blog post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) about fetching top row by group in SQL.

As described in the post, you could use either `IN` or `JOIN`.

Take `IN` for example:

```
SELECT * FROM post_table 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM post_table GROUP BY author_id);
```

The SQL could be written in QuerySet as:

```
Post.objects.filter(pk__in=
    Post.objects.order_by().values('author_id').annotate(
        max_id=models.Max('id')).values('max_id'))
```

The `QuerySet` pattern of `SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM post_table GROUP BY author_id` is:

```
Model.objects.order_by().values(...).annotate(foo=...).values('foo')
^------------^----------^-----------^-----------------^------------^
    \            \           \            \                \
base queryset     \        GROUP BY        \           SELECT column
or manager      remove possible           annotation part
                useless ordering          Min/Max/...
```

Also, you could wrap the SQL in `queryset.raw()` directly. If you choose the `JOIN` version, the `.raw()` way is clearer.

Note that the `IN` clause might have performance issue in your DB backend, you need to profile and tweak index if the performance is critical.

Comment: This post is really old but still really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

```
a = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
#next line will give you the latest post of this particular author
latest_post = a.post_set.latest('id')
```

Comment: but my question is, how to make this for all Authors, without iterate ("get the last Post of each Author in one ORM call", that mean a list of Posts without authors repeated)